# File paths that works with all directories

Tags: php, file, path

In PHP when we include or require some file using some **initializers** like the following. How can we overcome filepath issues which occurs if you include the same **initializer** in a sub-directory or different location.

```
<?php

// settings
$settings = array('config');

foreach ($settings as $setting) {
    require_once "../system/settings/{$setting}.php";
}

// neutrals
$neutrals = array('functions');

foreach ($neutrals as $neutral) {
    require_once "../system/neutrals/{$neutral}.php";
}

// helpers
$helpers = array('database', 'file', 'logger', 'user', 'session', 'database');

foreach ($helpers as $helper) {
    require_once "../system/helpers/{$helper}.php";
}

// models
$models = array('test');

foreach ($models as $model) {
    require_once "../system/models/{$model}.php";
}

?>
```

Above script is in a file **all_initializer.php**. The hurdle here is that i cant use the same initializer in a public sub-directory or other location as it will occur fatal errors (if its a required file) of file not found.

**EDIT**

For e.g. I am using this initialzer in a public folder in a **index.php** file then there's a sub-directory in the public folder **public/sub**. How can I use the same initializer in **public/sub/index.php** as I used in **public/index.php** ?

Comment: I don't really understand the specific problem you're describing, but there are a number of widely used solutions for file path problems and inconsistencies. Many sites and systems today have a configuration variable for the main path, which you can use everywhere else and then if the path changes, you only need to change one variable.

Comment: I didn't understand what your problem is...

Comment: This is stackoverflow.com community which never returns me thirsty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `file_exists` to avoid fatal errors

```
// neutrals
$neutrals = array('functions');

foreach ($neutrals as $neutral) {
    if (file_exists("../system/neutrals/{$neutral}.php") 
    {
        require_once "../system/neutrals/{$neutral}.php";
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some logging here so as to know that something went wrong
    }
}
```

As for the path issues you are referring to, you can include this file from anywhere so long as you supply the proper base path for your operations. Defining a `ROOT_PATH` in your `index.php` file would help you detect where your script is and what it needs to load.

So for instance if you have this structure:

```
/system
/system/neutrals
/system/models
/public
/public/index.php
```

in your `index.php` you can define a `ROOT_PATH` constant that will be used throughout the application and serve as a point of reference.

```
// this points to the folder that has /public and /system
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
```

You can also have a constant just for your system folder

```
define('SYSTEM_PATH', ROOT_PATH . '/system');
```

and then all your `require_once` declarations become:

```
require_once SYSTEM_PATH ."/neutrals/{$neutral}.php";
```

**EDIT**: Based on additional information in the question

```
Structure:
/all_includes.php
/system
/system/neutrals
/system/models
/public
/public/index.php
/public/sub/index_sub.php
```

In index.php you define

```
// this points to the folder that has /public and /system
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
```

and then:

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . '/all_includes.php';
```

to do your initialization. The same thing happens in the `public/sub/index_sub.php`.

Your `all_includes.php` becomes:

```
// neutrals
$neutrals = array('functions');

foreach ($neutrals as $neutral) {
    if (file_exists(ROOT_PATH . "/system/neutrals/{$neutral}.php") 
    {
        require_once ROOT_PATH . "/system/neutrals/{$neutral}.php";
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some logging here so as to know that something went wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the file based on your edits in the question. Have a look and let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: So thats my exact site folder :)

Comment: @YousufIqbal Don't worry about the vote up/down. The key is that you got the answer that helped you solve your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple.. don't use relative paths... in your `foreach` loops, you could do:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/thing.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way most of the php frameworks work is similar to the following, zend framework works like this:

Declare a constant APPLICATION_PATH and then make all the paths relative to this one.

```
define("APPLICATION_PATH", "/var/www/mysite");
```

And then all your requires will be relative to your APPLICATION_PATH.

```
require_once APPLICATION_PATH ."/system/helpers/{$helper}.php";
```

*** With this approach you can include files from whatever script without issues. Because all the paths are going to be relative to your APPLICATION_PATH.

Comment: You can event make php decide your APPLICATION_PATH automatically.
Write something like that:
**`define("APPLICATION_PATH", ___DIR___);`**
then use it to require other files.

Comment: Doing this you are defining your constant relative to the (current working directory) of the script where you declare the constant. If that is what you want , is ok, but that will force me to declare the  constant in an specific file. Otherwise i can do it in any place, just like the people from zend framework do it . They declare the APPLICATION_PATH in the application.ini file and then include this file in the bootstrap.php. I think this way is more flexible.

Comment: Usually I do it in beginning of script that is included in every other file. In other words - init script, which later loads all other files.
This way is more flexible in situation when you need to install it to different servers - in your case, you will need to update PATH everytime you move to a new server.

Comment: I understand you, but if you have any chance take a look at the boostraping section of zend framework. Is only one line that defines the application_path for the entire project. In case you need to change is just a single line.

Comment: I know :) However, changing even one line is not always fun :)

Answer (score -2):

the pathing problem can be solved in this way, you have one file that is always in the same place. for example you have (this is you public html)

```
.
..
folder/subfolder/filetoinclude.php
folder2/includein.php
thefilefolder/thefile.php
```

ok now in the file php you have a variable

```
$path=dirname(__FILE__);
```

this will always give you the absolute path to that file, then you ca use this $path variable and build your include paths around it.
in this example you have to include $path.'../folder/subfolder/filetoinclude.php'; 
The pint is to alway use the same point of origin, and not use relative paths.
and then you can make a custom include function in thefile.php, and then the things get really easy.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Read this http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer/